# Asynchronous Replicate API in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, replicate

I am writing a telegram bot that will generate images using this stable diffusion model: https://replicate.com/mbentley124/openjourney-img2img

I am using the replicate module. however, the code snippet below slows down the bot when someone sends a request.

```
async def txt2img(message, prompt, negative, stepMode, width, height):
print('Generating image for ' + str(message.chat.id))
output = replicate.run(
    "tstramer/midjourney-diffusion:436b051ebd8f68d23e83d22de5e198e0995357afef113768c20f0b6fcef23c8b",
    input={"prompt": "mdjrny-v4 " + prompt, "negative_prompt": negative, "num_inference_steps": stepMode*10, "width": width, "height": height}
)
print(output[0] + '\n')
return await message.answer_photo(output[0])
```

Please help to make this code asynchronous and it is desirable to add a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txt2img` is not asynchronous, because the `replicate.run` function you're using is a blocking function, lets use a library like `concurrent.futures` to call `replicate.run` in a separate thread.

Like in my example below, dont forget to put the loop somewhere in your code `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`

```
import concurrent.futures

async def txt2img(message, prompt, negative, stepMode, width, height):
    print('Generating image for ' + str(message.chat.id))

    def blocking_code():
        return replicate.run(
            "tstramer/midjourney-diffusion:436b051ebd8f68d23e83d22de5e198e0995357afef113768c20f0b6fcef23c8b",
            input={"prompt": "mdjrny-v4 " + prompt, "negative_prompt": negative, 
                   "num_inference_steps": stepMode*10, "width": width, "height": height}
        )

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future = executor.submit(blocking_code)
        output = await loop.run_in_executor(None, future.result)

    print(output[0] + '\n')
    return await message.answer_photo(output[0])
```